# Custom Minecraft launcher

Tags: launcher, minecraft, lzma

I want to create my own Minecraft launcher where when the player checks Force Update it downloads a modified minecraft.jar, an updated lwjgl (both not a big problem) and 2 extra folders in your .minecraft directory. I can do the first 2 by changing the MinecraftDownload directory to one on my own website and putting the modified files on my site, but i don't exactly know how to make it download and extract an archive into the .minecraft directory (i guess i will use lzma because the libs for that are already in there).

I am new to Java, but I did some very well vb.net programming so i know standard developing terms.

Comment: Try to google your questions before you ask them.. here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java

Answer (score 4):

0# This is not a real answer for the question.
To Launch Minecraft 1.5.2(old):

```
java -Djava.library.path=bin/natives -cp bin/* net.minecraft.client.Minecraft YOURUSERNAMEHERE
pause
```

To Launch New Minecraft:

```
java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -Djava.library.path=versions/1.8/1.8-natives-xxxxxxxxxxxx -cp
libraries/ here the minecraft 1.8 libraries (optain from 1.8.json)
versions/1.8/1.8.jar
net.minecraft.client.main.Main
--username yourusername
--version 1.8
--assetsdir assest 
--assetindex 1.8
--accesstoken null
--userproperties {}
```

To understand this commands read this posts:

[Launch minecraft 1.6.4 from command line with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486866/launch-minecraft-1-6-4-from-command-line-with-c-sharp)

[Launch Minecraft from command line - usename and password as prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531917/launch-minecraft-from-command-line-usename-and-password-as-prefix)

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156000/launching-minecraft-1-7-4-from-the-command-line

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `userProperties` argument?

Answer (score -3):

Unpack bin/minecraft.jar and take a look inside

Happy hacking.